# when to split view and controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, design-patterns

i often do not split view and controller related things correctly.

1. should i always subclass a uiview if i want custom uibuttons and backgrounds in my app and add style related stuff in my view or should i handle this in my controller? or probably subclass a uibutton?
2. what about alignings? when should i subclass a uiview, add buttons to it and align then or handle this in my controller?

thanks for your hints!
please leave some comments if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should i always subclass a uiview if I want custom uibuttons and
>   backgrounds in my app and add style related stuff in my view

If your need are basic, you coan just insert wanted elements as subviews of your view without having to subclass anything. Buttons and views have enough properties to handle those simple needs. But everything depends on what are those needs.

> Should i handle this in my controller? or probably subclass a
>   uibutton?

Subclassing UIButton for UIButton behaviour is not a bad idea :-)  But as said before, what do you need as special behaviour ? A special image : there is a property for that. A special reaction on events, manage it into the controller on IBActions. A UIButton with UFO behaviours, ok, let's subclass it.

> What about alignings? when should i subclass a uiview, add buttons to
>   it and align then or handle this in my controller?

Hmmm... I guess never. This can (should) be done in the controller. The controller controls the whole UIItems. So if you want to align one item regarding another, do it into the controller. If you want to align special graphics or text that is displayed into the button, sublass it and manage that in the `drawRect` method.